# configuring jupyter dashboard server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to create a jupyter dashboard server but when I click

`File-> Deploy as-> Dashboard on jupyter dashboard server`

I get the following error message

> No dashboard server configured

I tried to look for a tutorial online but couldn't find one. 
Can you please help me find a reference?

thanks.